# Nice proof of a polynomial root $x \in [0, 1]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing, contest-math

> Prove that if
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k+1} = 0$$
>   then
>   $$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\cdot x^n = 0$$
>   for some $x$ in $[0,1]$. ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOAiU.png))

So:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k+1} = 0$$

We must prove:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\cdot x^n = 0$$

So $f(x) = a_0$. Now:

$$a_0 = -\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k+1}$$

Now, I just need to verify that $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{a_k}{k+1} > 0$

Thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** The first sum equals $\int_0^1 p(x)\, dx$.

Comment: No integration allowed (this is the derivative section).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**: Define a polynomial $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n a_k\frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1}$ and then apply Rolle's theorem (Note that $f(0)=f(1)=0$ ).

Comment: How is $f(1) = 0$? I see: $f(1) = \sum a_k \frac{1}{k+1}$ how does that evaluate to $0$?

Comment: @Lebes see the given condition in the question

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

- $a_0 + \ldots + \dfrac{a_n}{n+1} = \displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{1}(a_nx^n + \ldots + a_0) dx$
- Intermediate value theorem